# delete c in void insert() prints infinite numbers, if I comment it out I get correct output

Tags: c++

This program creates and prints a link list in cpp
When this program runs an infinite no. of numbers start printing in the console

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node* next;
};

class Node* head = NULL;
int length = 0;
```

In this function if i comment out delete c then it works, I don't know why delete c is causing problem

```
void insert(int data) {
    class Node* newNode = NULL;
    newNode = new Node();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
        length++;
    }
    else {
        class Node* c = head;
        while(c->next != NULL) {
        c = c->next;
        }
        c->next = newNode;
        length++;
        delete c;
    }
}
```

Here delete c causes no issues

```
void print() {
    class Node* c = head;
    while(c != NULL) {
        cout<<c->data<<endl;
        c = c->next;
    }
    cout<<"Length of link list = "<<length<<endl;
    delete c;
}
```

main function

```
int main() {
    cout<<"Hello Wrold"<<endl;
    insert(5);
    insert(10);
    insert(15);
    insert(20);
    print();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Why do you write `delete c;`? You want to delete the last node in the list?

Comment: Also your checks for causing a problem or not will not work with undefined behavior. What I mean is with undefined behavior your code will sometimes work correctly even though the code is broken / program is malformed. It does not have to crash or misbehave. This is one of the worst behaviors of UB when the code appears to work but the program is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `insert` function, the loop condition is `c->next != NULL`. Therefore `c` points at an in-use node after the loop, and `delete c;` destroys the node and cause trouble.

In other hand, the loop condition in your `print` function is `c != NULL`. Therefore `c` will be `NULL` after the loop and `delete c;` won't cause trouble because deleting `NULL` is defined to do nothing.